# JQuery animate scrollTop strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm making a simple calendar in PHP in the form of a vertical table. When the page loads I want it to scroll automatically to the current day with an animation.

I chose to create it myself because classes available on the internet don't allow to show the content in the way I want.

*This is always working correctly in Chrome on Windows PC, but in Edge and Chrome on Android it only works in Incognito mode or 1 single time after clearing the cache.*

I tried every solution suggested on the internet, but nothing works.

- Removing viewport
- Only animate $('body')
- Remove overflow: hidden
- Set overflow hidden first, then animate and then set overflow again to auto
- Remove height: 100%
- Adding cache headers in HTML

I don't know anymore what to do. What could be the problem?

Please keep in mind that I'm just a beginning developer, doing this in my spare time only.

**The current code:**

[PS: I know it is better to seperate HTML and CSS, but it is just a test. Also, the variables and their values are simplified in the example.]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META charset = "UTF-8">
        <META name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV = "CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT = "NO-CACHE">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV = "EXPIRES" CONTENT = "Mon, 22 Jul 2002 00:00:01 GMT">
        <META http-equiv = "pragma" content = "no-cache">
        <LINK rel = "stylesheet" href = "addins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <STYLE>
            body, html {
                background-color: #<?php echo $backgroundcolor; ?>;
                color: #<?php echo $textcolor; ?>;
                line-height: 1;
                font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
            <!-- Styles for other elements are here, but not relevant for the example -->
        </STYLE>
        <SCRIPT src = "addins/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
        <SCRIPT src = "addins/jQueryUI/jquery-ui.min.js"></SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <DIV id = "loading" class = "loading">
            <!-- Loading image and text comes here -->
        </DIV>
        <DIV id = "pagecontent" style = "display: none;">
<?php
    /* Setting PHP vars here. */
?>
            <!-- Here is the header of the page including buttons to go to the next or previous month. -->
<?php
    for ($thisdaynumber = 1; $thisdaynumber <= $numberofdaysinmonth; $thisdaynumber++) {
?>
            <DIV id = "<?php echo "day".$thisdaynumber;?>">
                <TABLE id = "<?php echo "titletable".$thisdaynumber; ?>">
                    <TR>
<?php
                    echo "<TD";
                    if ($thisdate == $currentdate) {
                        echo " style = \"color: #".$currentdaycolor.";\"";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo " style = \"color: #".$generalcolor.";\"";
                    }
                    echo ">";
                        echo "".$thisweekdayname."";
                        echo "<BR><b>".$thisdaynumber."</b>";
                    echo "</TD>";
?>
                    </TR>
                </TABLE>
                <TABLE id = "<?php echo "contenttable".$thisdaynumber; ?>">
                    <!-- Here is the content for this date -->
                </TABLE>
            </DIV>
<?php
    }
?>
            <SCRIPT>
                // Some javascript functions here
                $(window).on('load', function() {
                    // Make a particular day stand out on request
                    var navday = "<?php echo $_GET['navday']; ?>";
                    var flashday = "<?php echo $_GET['flashday']; ?>";
                    if (navday != "") {
                        var navelementname = "#day" + navday;
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(navelementname).offset().top - 100
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                    if (flashday != "") {
                        var flashelementname = "#day" + flashday;
                        var flashcolor = "#<?php echo $flashcolor; ?>";
                        flashit(flashelementname, flashcolor);
                    }
                    // If no navday chosen and the current month is loaded, scroll to current day
                    var currentmonthloaded = "<?php echo $currentmonthloaded; ?>";
                    var currentdaynumber = "<?php echo $currentdaynumber; ?>";
                    if (currentmonthloaded == "Y" && navday == "") {
                        var currentdayelementname = "#day" + currentdaynumber;
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $(currentdayelementname).offset().top - 100
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('#pagecontent').show();
                });
           </SCRIPT>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Bart

Comment: maybe it´s easier to help if you just post the generated code instead of all those echos

Comment: as far as i can see, your code will **always** run `$(window).scrollTop(0);` in the documet).ready part

Comment: @johnSmith Yes thanks, I edited the question. Also, I removed the scrollTop(0) in document.ready, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: maybe it has to do with you initially hidden `#pagecontent`, like at the moment of execution the scrolltop of the day is maybe 0 because its hidden or sth like this

Comment: @johnSmith The problem was indeed with the hiding and showing of the `#pagecontent`. jQuery `.show()` sets the display type back to the initial value (inline by default). I changed it to `.css('display', 'block')` and now it's working fine. Actually I don't really understand very why this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the hiding and showing of the `#pagecontent`. jQuery `.show()` sets the display type back to the initial value (inline by default). I changed it to `.css('display', 'block')` and now it's working fine. Actually I don't really understand very why this solves my problem.